# Google Storage Cloud: Bucket is a requester pays bucket

Tags: storage, cloud, google

When I enter the public link (photo) available in Google Cloud Storage, that I uploaded see such error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Error>
<Code>UserProjectMissing</Code>
<Message>Bucket is a requester pays bucket but no user project provided.</Message>
<Details>Bucket is Requester Pays bucket but no billing project id provided for non-owner.</Details>
</Error>
```

Permission set to allUsers

Everything worked very well in Free Trial, now I have created a new billing account and deposited 10 Euros, activated and give the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably due to the Free-Trial period that ended. Your GCS bucket might be linked with your trial account somehow. The error message "no billing project id provided" suggests it needs a billing account even if your object is public.

I would suggest simply creating a new bucket in your paid project and put your object there for testing.